# Вызвано исключение: нарушение доступа для чтения?

Tags: c++

```
#pragma once
#include "Headers.h"

std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> getPtr(char c)
{
    if (c == 'W') return std::make_shared<W>();
    else if (c == 'P') return std::make_shared<P>();
}

class Class
{
public:
    Class() = default;
    ~Class() = default;

    void read(std::istream&);
    void print(std::ostream&);

    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> ClassList;
private:
};

void Class::read(std::istream& in)
{
    while (!in.eof())
    {
        char c;
        in >> c;
        std::shared_ptr<BaseClass> ptr = getPtr(c);
        ptr->read(in);
        ClassList.push_back(ptr);
    }
}
void Class::print(std::ostream& out)
{
    std::ostream_iterator<std::shared_ptr<BaseClass>> _out(out);
    std::copy(TarifsList.begin(), TarifsList.end(), _out);
}
```

Ошибка на этапе выполнения, не могу найти решение.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Давайте код целиком, или поправьте его до воспроизводимого прмиера. Хотя бы ошибку напишите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`while (!in.eof())` - ошибка, потому что EOF срабатывает только после неудачной попытки чтения за концом файла.

Правильно так:

```
char c;
while (in >> c) {...}
```

---

Еще, писать `~Class() = default;` - вредно для здоровья, потому что ваш класс нельзя будет переместить, и вместо этого он будет всегда копироваться (если не предпринять каких-то специальных мер против этого).

Comment: Минуточку, как это дефольный деструктор влияет на дефолтный мув-конструктор?

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/j63bfT8Kh

Comment: @megorit Он отключает его генерацию, а копируюший оставляет, так что он будет тихо использоваться вместо перемещающего. Присваивание аналогично. Попозже пример добавлю.

Comment: @megorit Держите пример: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bzav4q87K

Comment: Вы думаете, слет программы из-за этого? Откровенно говоря, не вижу оснований для такого вывода. Не поясните?

Comment: @Harry Выполнение доходит до конца `getPtr` без return, если ему дать неправильную букву (а цикл по `eof` как раз выдает одну мусорную букву в конце). Оно либо сразу падает, либо возвращает плохой указатель, на котором потом падает `->read()`.

Comment: Да, точно... это я как-то не обратил внимания... Спасибо!